# sfWidgetFormDate for sfWidgetFormInputText with two fields

Tags: php, symfony1, widget, symfony-1.4

I have the statement

```
$this->setWidget('one_date', new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format' => '%year%  %month%' )));
```

`one_date` in MySQL is a timestamp. This shows me the selected list with year and selected list with month. How can i change this for input text for month and input text for year? If I try changing with: `sfWidgetFormInputText` then I have an error:

> sfWidgetFormInputText does not support
>   the following options: 'format',
>   'years'.

Answer (score 1):

You would need two separate text fields that you combine after submission to create your one_date.
Doing it this way could make validation tricky.

```
$this->setWidgets(array(
      'month' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'year' => new sfWidgetFormInputText()
   ));
$this->setValidators(array(
      'month' => new sfValidatorInteger(),
      'year' => new sfValidatorInteger()
      ));
```

```
if ($this->form->isValid()) {
      $one_date = $this->form->getValue('month') . $this->form->getValue('year');
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i have $this->setWidget('one_date', new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format' => '%year%  %month%' )));
and not widget month and year. i will seperate widget one_date like format... in my database is field one_date (timestamp)

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. I thought you wanted two text input fields, one for month and one for year? My method for achieving this would be to create widgets for month and year then after validation combine them to get your $one_date value.